# Logistic regression in R with millions of observations and rare events

Tags: r, logistic-regression, large-data

I'm working with a large data set of ~ 15 million observations in R. I'm trying to run a logistic regression to predict a binary dependant variable ("HasShared").
As the event of sharing is very rare (less than 1%), I triedto use the logistf regression in order to handle the rare events issues. I have 48 variables in my data set, only 6 of them should participate in the regression. I have extra RAM as I'm working on a virtual machine on Google cloud platform, and changed my RAM to be around 100 GB.
When I'm trying to run the logistf model - the run never ends. I waited for more than 2 hours and it didn't finish. So this seem infeasible.
I read that there's a package which supposed to handle regressions of very large datasets (biglm), but I'm looking for a solution that will both handle my large dataset AND the rare event issue. Is there such a combined solution?

Comment: The "rare event issue" is also known as imbalanced classification problem and `SMOTE` function from `DMwR` package is useful to address this problem see [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DMwR/) and [SMOTE paper](http://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-14-106)

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that invites opinion rather than solution. I'm tempted to suggest your problem lies here 'I'm working on a virtual machine'. A virtual machine, singular. Maybe a product that can share the load across multiple virtual machines? RHadoop? I've recently finished an introductory course on predictive analytics. The course introduced HPE Vertica, a SQL based solution with statistical analysis functionality.

https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/predictive-analytics

And yes, I would rather have posted this as a comment but I don't have the experience points.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you build your cost function minimization algorithm manually rather than using a black box library. In this case you will be able to see the progress in your cost function value (if you use Rstudio you can refresh variables), play with learning rate alpha etc. Below is is how it is implemented with gradient descent:

```
# generate some data:

x1 = rnorm(1000)          
x2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         
y = pr > 0.5               

# apply gradient descent to minimize cost function:

alpha = 0.001

m = length(y)

X = as.matrix(cbind(x0 = rep(1,m), x1,  x2))
Y = y
n = ncol(X)
THETA = rep(0, n)

H_theta = function(i){
  1/(1+exp(-(t(THETA) %*% X[i,]) ) )
}

J_theta <- function(){ -(1/m)*(  sum(  Y*log(mapply(H_theta, 1:m))  +   (1-Y)*log(1 - (mapply(H_theta, 1:m)) )   ) ) }

gradient_j <- function(j){sum((mapply(H_theta, 1:m) - Y)*X[,j]) }


for(i in 1:1000){
  NEW_THETA <- THETA - alpha*mapply(gradient_j, 1:n)
  THETA <- NEW_THETA
  cost = J_theta()
}
predicted_y = mapply(H_theta, 1:m)>0.5

# see results:
table(y == predicted_y)
```

Alternatively, you could build Apache Spark cluster and use their logistic regression algorithm.